# Jest Appears to Skip Tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm doing some prototyping with Jest, and I'm running into a strange issue. My tests sit in a separate file that exports the tests as functions. I then have another file that imports the tests and runs them as a suite. The idea being that I can dynamically create a test suite using a config file to pull in the tests I want.

I'm trying to use a `import` expression to load the files. That works as expected. I see the tests but Jest appears to skip the test. The test is outputted in the console but it's neither a pass or fail. It appears the same way a skipped test is run.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

I have my file containing my tests:

```
import { sayHello } from '../../src/say-hello';

const testReturnMessage = () => {
    return it('should return the correct message', () => {
        expect(sayHello('Example')).toBe('Hello Example');
    });
};
export const SayHelloTests = {
    testReturnMessage,
};
```

Then I use `import()` to pull it into a test suite:

```
import('./sayHelloModule').then((module) => {
    module.SayHelloTests.testReturnMessage();
}).catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

This is what the jest output looks like. I'm using codesandbox.io to do my prototype:
[image]

I know my test works because when I do it the normal way I get a pass.

```
import { SayHelloTests } from './sayHelloModule';
SayHelloTests.testReturnMessage();
```

Here is the test passing:
[image]

This has been driving me crazy because it should work, and I can't figure out why it's not. I'm guessing it has something to do with Jest because if I import a non-test function it runs just fine. Does anyone have any thoughts or have seen something like this before?

Comment: I feel like there might be something async related that’s causing this. Is it possible that the tests look like they’re skipped not because they’re not run but because they never complete?

Comment: You can't call `it` asynchronously. All tests should be defined at the time when test run starts. *I'm trying to use a import expression to load the files* - dynamic import is async. Use require if you need, Jest runs in Node environment and isn't ready yet to use ESM in real world testing.

Comment: @EstusFlask switching to `require` solved the problem. It's weird that non-tests functions worked just fine with `import()` but the actual test wouldn't.

Comment: There's nothing weird. As I said, it's async. And Jest expects all known tests to be synchronously declared